# Uploaded HttpPostedFile is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On the View:

```
<% =Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data "})%>
  <input type="file" name="postedFile" />
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

In the Controller, there's something like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult About(HttpPostedFile postedFile)
{
    //but postedFile is null 
    View();
}
```

`postedFile` is null in About(). How do I upload the file?

Comment: checkout [Scott Hansleman's blog entry](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

Comment: just noting for anyone else who encounter the same problem.. The actual problem here is `enctype="multipart/form-data "` there is a space at the end of attribute value and believe me, Firefox will reset it to default enctype. You will not notice it in chrome. I have faced the same problem and when I spotted and removed that extra space, everything went well..! Hope it will save someone's few minutes..!

Answer (score 36):

Use HttpPostedFileBase (not HttpPostedFile) and also name the parameter exactly as in the form. eg. if you have

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" />
```

you have to have the method head:

```
public ActionResult About(HttpPostedFileBase file1)
```

Comment: actually only the name is mandatory (and has to conform to the method parameters name). The id is only used by javascript and css (simplified).

Comment: I had the exact same problem and once changing my action parameter type from `HttpPostedFile` to `HttpPostedFileBase`, it worked. So that suggestion should be stressed.

Comment: saved my day, this is interesting, is it a bug or intended behavior?

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't answer why your parameter is null, but you can dig into the request directly. This might not be the most "MVC" way of doing this though. try this in your method body:

```
var upload = Request.Files["postedFile"]
if (upload.ContentLength > 0)
{
  // Do whatever
}
```

To be more "MVC, "You could pull that code out of your controller into an IModelBinder implementation and using a custom object as a parameter to your method. This [Scott Hanselman blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx) shows the steps to implement a custom ModelBinder.

Answer (score 6):

use this

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase excelfile)
```

change `HttpPostedFile` for `HttpPostedFileBase`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem:

You have to define a name AND id for the input element:

```
<input type="file" name="postedFile" id="postedFileId"  />
```

Best regards

Stefan

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the space from the end of enctype attribute:

```
new {enctype="multipart/form-data "} => new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also get some quirks with `<%= Html.BeginForm ...%>`. So, I use the using. Again, on the Controller side, I just grab my uploaded files form the request object.

Try this. It works:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
   {%>

    <input type="file" id="postedFile" name="PostedFile" />
    <input type="submit" />

<%
}
```

%>

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Post(FormCollection form)
    {
      HttpPostedFileBase postedFile =   Request.Files["PostedFile"];
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Just copy and paste my controller action and view. It works for me. Note that my action method is not taking HttpPostedFile as argument.

Comment: `FormCollection form` is not needed. `Request.Files["PostedFile"];` can be changed to `Request.Files[0];`.  If using Razor, you just need an `@` before the `using` and get rid of all of the `<%` and `%>` tags. Can change `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` to `[HttpPost]`, too.  I got it working with those changes.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of MVC are you using?
Right now with the RC candidate I tried using HttpPostedFile and I got an "does not have a blank constructor error." I had to use HttpPostedFileBase.

More importantly though, is the version of MVC you're running on, depending on the version, how your retrieve a posted file will be different.

Answer (score 2):

An empty space after "multipart/form-data " is the real issue...

Answer (score 2):

are you using jquery mobile? if yes, you'll need to set @data_ajax to false

```
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, I have found that the form declaration in which the file upload lies must always have

```
new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the bits you need to uplaod a file

```
//in your model 
public partial class Profile
{
    [DisplayName("Image Upload")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)] 
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload { get; set; }
}



// in your view
@model ProjName.Blabla.Profile

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload" value="Choose File" class="form-control" />

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
```

Add `encType="multipart/form-data"` to your form.